# Calculate the Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: code-golf, math, number

Calculate the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) to the maximum primitive precision in your language (for C-family, that would be `double` or `long double`, `var` in JS, etc.) No need for `BigDecimal` or the like unless you need it to use a `double`-equivalent precision.

1. Efficiency (be sane) doesn't matter.
2. If it's not in a common language, I can't test it, but I hope somebody does.
3. **No libraries or built-in math functions.**
4. Recursion is cool!

See my JS entry for a sample program.

Comment: Judging by your example implementation it only needs to work for real inputs greater 1?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes.

Comment: And what about those math functions? You're using the power function yourself. Which math functions are allowed and which aren't?

Comment: How is input/output to be handled? Examples?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Okay. Only basic math functions equivalent to Java/JS's `Math`.

Comment: I think without power function you will be pretty lost, and many programming languages do not require a math library for calculating powers! The next thing that is unclear: how dos `double` apply to complex arguments? (Since the zeta function is defined for Re(z)>0 where z is complex.)

Comment: @SimonKuang You may want to list those functions in your question.

Comment: I was hovering over the submit post button right when it got closed.  That's life I guess :P

Answer (score -1):

## JavaScript (Chrome): 78

```js
function zeta(r){for(var t=0,a=1,n=1;t!=a;a=t,t+=1/Math.pow(n++,r));return t}
```

Comment: No math libraries

Comment: And apart from that I think it will fail for `r=1+epsilon` where `epsilon>0` small enough. Even though one summand might be smaller than working precision, the sum of the following summands can be bigger. Best example for this is the series `sum 1/n for n=1 to infinity = zeta(1)`.