# Evaluate the Riemann Zeta Function at a Complex Number

Tags: code-golf, math, complex-numbers, calculus

## Introduction

I found [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35727/calculate-the-riemann-zeta-function) that was closed because it was unclear, yet it was a nice idea. I'll do my best to make this into a clear challenge.

The [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) is a special function that is defined as the analytical continuation of

[image]

to the complex plane. There are many equivalent formulas for it which makes it interesting for code golf.

## Challenge

Write a program that takes 2 floats as input (the real and imaginary part of a complex number) and evaluates the Riemann Zeta function at that point.

**Rules**

- Input and output via console OR function input and return value
- Built in complex numbers are not allowed, use floats (number, double, ...)
- No mathematical functions except `+ - * / pow log` and real valued trig functions (if you want to integrate, use the gamma function, ... you must include this functions definition in the code)
- Input: 2 floats
- Output: 2 floats
- Your code must contain value that gives theoretically arbitrary precision when made arbitrary large/small
- The behaviour at input 1 is not important (this is the only pole of this function)

Shortest code in bytes wins!

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> 2, 0

Output:

> 1.6449340668482266, 0

Input:

> 1, 1

Output:

> 0.5821580597520037, -0.9268485643308071

Input:

> -1, 0

Output:

> -0.08333333333333559, 0

Comment: What's the required output precision? I'm not sure I understand _Your code must contain value that gives theoretically arbitrary precision when made arbitrary large/small_. Do you mean like a loop maximum value than when increased without bound gives increased precision? Can that value be hard-coded?

Comment: @DonMuesli This means the precision depends on a parameter, say N, which you may give any value you like, but for any given precision, you can make N small or large enough to achieve that precision. The word theoretically is there because you must not worry about the limited precision of the machine or language.

Comment: To further clarify N: is it sufficient that for any bound `eps` and input `x` there exists an `N` which calculates `zeta(x)` to within `eps`; or must there exist an `N` which depends only on `eps` and guarantees that for any `x` (or perhaps for any `x` more than a given function of `eps` from the pole) it achieves the bound; or may `N` depend on `x`, but answers should explain how to calculate `N` given `x` and `eps`? (My analytical number theory isn't up to much, but I suspect that options 2 and 3 are going to be beyond all but one or two regular posters).

Comment: @PeterTaylor N large enough: For any `x` and for any `eps` there must exist a `P` such that for all `N>P` the output is closer than `eps` to the exact value. Is this clear? Do I need to clarify it for the case with N small enough?

Comment: No, that's clear enough.

Answer (score 8):

## Python - 385

This is a straightforward implementation of Equation 21 from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html This uses Python's convention for optional arguments; if you want to specify a precision, you can pass a third argument to the function, otherwise it uses 1e-24 by default.

```
import numpy as N
def z(r,i,E=1e-24):
 R=0;I=0;n=0;
 while(True):
  a=0;b=0;m=2**(-n-1)
  for k in range(0,n+1):
   M=(-1)**k*N.product([x/(x-(n-k))for x in range(n-k+1,n+1)]);A=(k+1)**-r;t=-i*N.log(k+1);a+=M*A*N.cos(t);b+=M*A*N.sin(t)
  a*=m;b*=m;R+=a;I+=b;n+=1
  if a*a+b*b<E:break
 A=2**(1-r);t=-i*N.log(2);a=1-A*N.cos(t);b=-A*N.sin(t);d=a*a+b*b;a=a/d;b=-b/d
 print(R*a-I*b,R*b+I*a)
```

Comment: `z(2,0)` gives an incorrect value, should be pi^2/6.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>303</s> <s>297</s> 298 bytes

This answer is based on [R.T.'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75540/47581) with several modifications:

- First, `Binomial(n, k)` is defined as `p = p * (n-k) / (k+1)` which changes `Binomial(n,k)` to `Binomial(n,k+1)` with every pass of the for loop.
- Second, `(-1)**k * Binomial(n,k)` became `p = p * (k-n) / (k+1)` which flips the sign at every step of the for loop.
- Third, the `while` loop has been changed to immediately check if `a*a + b*b < E`.
- Fourth, the bitwise not operator `~` is used in several places where they would aid in golfing, using identities such as `-n-1 == ~n`, `n+1 == -~n`, and `n-1 == ~-n`. This only works for ints, however, and not floats.

Several other small modifications were made for better golfing, such as putting the `for` loop on one line and the call to `print` on one line with the code before it.

Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVA7b8IwEN75FTfaZxvitF2wrhIDQwYYsiIGpwSwQpzIuGrC0L@exqr6WO6@7x7fPfoxXjv/NE2u7bsQobXxCvYO@8WpPsODBenklnStnjO@XkBJBXnKjKWK9AI@ru5Wg0UrKqxet3MBpExmetKmpRzx08@xcxegAechWH@pmZZe5Hy9o37VIAbTI7FGaeX5qjGRlMP98tZdWMONFbSb2Vt3Z5Gb6pvdnZ9ZmoXUmiqZUpA1haDKeJEW26TZTKvA/wvm3Ayk1eZPcaTNr6A50YCDGHE0oY7vwbMSB1XgyFcnOeNRFDjMeErnlBKKdNHhkEvIjhIOWoJOXumfwPIloWP6CkAfnI/swVIj59MX)

**Edit:** -6 bytes from a number of small changes.

**Edit:** +1 byte from fixing an error with float handling, with thanks to [mostlyWright](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/120478/mostlywright) for pointing out the error.

```python
import math as N
def z(r,i,E=1e-40):
 R=I=n=0;a=b=1
 while a*a+b*b>E:
  a=b=0;p=1;m=2**~n
  for k in range(1,n+2):M=p/k**r;p*=(k-1-n)/k;t=-i*N.log(k);a+=M*N.cos(t);b+=M*N.sin(t)
  a*=m;b*=m;R+=a;I+=b;n+=1
 A=2**(1-r;t=-i*N.log(2);x=1-A*N.cos(t);y=A*N.sin(t);d=x*x+y*y;return(R*x-I*y)/d,(R*y+I*x)/d
```

Comment: doesnt work for r (float)

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, <s>413 315</s> 292 bytes

```
p(n,a,b)==(x:=log(n^b);y:=n^a;[y*cos(x),y*sin(x)]);z(a,b)==(r:=[0.,0.];e:=10^-digits();t:=p(2,1-a,-b);y:=(1-t.1)^2+t.2^2;y=0=>[];m:=(1-t.1)/y;q:=t.2/y;n:=0;repeat(w:=2^(-n-1);abs(w)<e=>break;r:=r+w*reduce(+,[(-1)^k*binomial(n,k)*p(k+1,-a,-b) for k in 0..n]);n:=n+1);[r.1*m-q*r.2,m*r.2+r.1*q])
```

This would implement too the equation 21 from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html 
The above should be the one iterpreted Axiom function z(a,b) here 16x slower than this below function Zeta(a,b)[that should be the one compiled] all ungolfed and commented
[1 second for Zeta() against 16 seconds for z() for one value of 20 digits afther the float point]. For the digit question, one would choose the precision by calling digits(); function, for example digits(10);z(1,1) should print 10 digits after the point, but digits(50);z(1,1) should print 50 digits after the point.

```
-- elevImm(n,a,b)=n^(a+i*b)=r+i*v=[r,v]
elevImm(n:INT,a:Float,b:Float):Vector Float==(x:=log(n^b);y:=n^a;[y*cos(x),y*sin(x)]::Vector Float);

--                      +oo               n
--                      ---              ---
--             1        \       1        \            n 
--zeta(s)= ---------- * /     ------  *  /    (-1)^k(   )(k+1)^(-s)
--          1-2^(1-s)   ---n  2^(n+1)    ---k         k  
--                       0                0


Zeta(a:Float,b:Float):List Float==
  r:Vector Float:=[0.,0.]; e:=10^-digits()

  -- 1/(1-2^(1-s))=1/(1-x-i*y)=(1-x+iy)/((1-x)^2+y^2)=(1-x)/((1-x)^2+y^2)+i*y/((1-x)^2+y^2)    

  t:=elevImm(2,1-a,-b);
  y:=(1-t.1)^2+t.2^2;
  y=0=>[] 
  m:=(1-t.1)/y; 
  q:=t.2/y
  n:=0
  repeat
     w:=2^(-n-1)
     abs(w)<e=>break  --- this always terminate because n increase
     r:=r+w*reduce(+,[(-1)^k*binomial(n,k)*elevImm(k+1,-a,-b) for k in 0..n])
     n:=n+1
  -- (m+iq)(r1+ir2)=(m*r1-q*r2)+i(m*r2+q*r1)
  [r.1*m-q*r.2,m*r.2+r.1*q]

this is one test for the z(a,b) function above:

(10) -> z(2,0)
   (10)  [1.6449340668 482264365,0.0]
                                              Type: List Expression Float
(11) -> z(1,1)
   (11)  [0.5821580597 520036482,- 0.9268485643 3080707654]
                                              Type: List Expression Float
(12) -> z(-1,0)
   (12)  [- 0.0833333333 3333333333 3,0.0]
                                              Type: List Expression Float
(13) -> z(1,0)
   (13)  []
```